# Simple confirmation modal

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal

I want to use ng2 bs3 modal to confirm user action. 
But i don't know how to get callback from my modal.
For example:

```
@ViewChild('confirmModal') confirm: confirmModal;
deleteItem(){
    if(this.confirm.open()){
        delete
    }
    else{
        not delete
    }
}
```

And shortened modal code

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="modal.dismiss()">Cancel</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="modal.close()">Ok</button>
export class confirmModal{
    close() {
        this.modal.close();
    }
    open(){
        this.modal.open()
    }
}
```

How to return true or false depending on the user's choice.
Thank you in advance for your answer.